# How to encrypt using jsencryption in client and decrypt in .NET

Tags: javascript, c#, encryption, cryptography

I'm trying to use http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/index.html on the client side to encrypt a value.

So I generate a public/private key using the tool, then I convert this into an XML file that .NET uses with this utility. https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter

But when I try to decrypt the sample text, I don't arrive at the same result.

How to replicate:
go to: http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/index.html
copy the private and public keys
copy the test string
click on encrypt and copy the resulting encrypted string

go to: http://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/index.html
use PEM to XML option,
use the private key to generate the PEM

save the PEM to a file or the clipboard.

Here is my .NET code to try to decrypt the encrypted value:

```
        // Select target CSP
        var cspParams = new CspParameters();
        cspParams.ProviderType = 1; // PROV_RSA_FULL 
        var rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(cspParams);

        var privateKeyText = "<replace this with the private key PEM>";
        // Import private/public key pair
        rsaProvider.FromXmlString(privateKeyText);

        var encryptedBytes = Convert.FromBase64String("<replace this with the encrypted string>");

        // Decrypt text
        var plainBytes = rsaProvider.Decrypt(encryptedBytes, false);

        // Write decrypted text to file
        var plainText = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(plainBytes);

        // the plainText value does not equal the test value!!!!!
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, or I might be missing something. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: @noel see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27727024/encypt-in-javascript-will-not-decrypt-in-c-sharp/27727277#27727277